# Hide checkbox using css

Tags: css

I have the code, which I get it from inspecting:

```
<td class=ox-list-pair style>
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected" value="selected:0" onclick="openxava.onSelectElement('CkSurvey','Sport','null','row=0,viewObject=xava_view',this.checked,'ox_CkSurvey_Sport__0',false,'','border-bottom: 1px solid;','',false,false,0,'xava_tab')">
</td>
```

I have tried to hide the checkbox but none of them success.
My attempts:

```
input[type=checkbox].ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected {
     display: none;
}

ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected {
     display: none;
}

.ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected input[type="checkbox"]{
     display:none;
}
```

Please note that `<td>` is valid as it is inside `<tr>` as well as `<table>`.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to apply css to name attribute instead use class or id

Comment: Do you need to hide this one checkbox only or all of them ? Do you have to use CSS only or JS is fine as well ?

Comment: @j-printemps I need to hide this checkbox only by using CSS.

Comment: Hi all, I found the solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on CSS selectors.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

You are trying to hide the check box with the class "ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected", but that doesn't exist.

You need to do this:

```
input[type=checkbox][name=ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Try without the `[type=checkbox]`. If that works, I'll update the answer

Comment: Also, does it work with just `input[type=checkbox]`? That should hide all checkboxes, but try it just for testing

Comment: sorry your solution is working. I made a mistake without clear cache and cookie.

Comment: You know that you don't need to clear cache every time you make any changes to your website. You can just do a hard reload which will fetch all files from source (not cache) which is ctrl+shift+R on chrome

Answer (score 1):

Is your `<td>` valid? What makes a `<td>` valid is:

> 1. It must be in a `<tr>`
> 2. That `<tr>` must be in a `<table>`

Technically `<tr>` must be in a `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, or `<tfoot>` but the browser will create a `<tbody>` by default if there's a `<table>`.

In the demo there's:

- a `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, and your messy checkbox.
- a `<td>` and a simple checkbox.

**Note:** The selector is `td.ox-list-pair > input[type="checkbox"]` and it successfully hides the messy checkbox and fails to hide the simple checkbox. So as you can see that the browser will ignore an invalid `<td>` and everything within it. I'm going out on a limb and assume that your `<td>` is not inside a `<tr>` and/or `<table>`.

### Demo

```js
$('td.ox-list-pair > input[type="checkbox"]').css('display', 'none');
```

```css
b {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='ox-list-pair' style>
      <input type="CHECKBOX" name="ox_CkSurvey_Sport__xava_selected" value="selected:0" onclick="openxava.onSelectElement('CkSurvey','Sport','null','row=0,viewObject=xava_view',this.checked,'ox_CkSurvey_Sport__0',false,'','border-bottom: 1px solid;','',false,false,0,'xava_tab')">I'm
      in a valid cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<td class='ox-list-pair'>
  <input type="CHECKBOX">I'm in an <b>invalid</b> cell
</td>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, the <td> is inside the <tr> and also the <table>. I have edited in my post. Thanks.